# Whats the reason for segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

The code runs and asks for the command. I am able to put in input but after I hit enter I get a segmentation fault. Struggling to understand what is the reason for this. I pretty sure it has something to do with the cin as thats were it crashes but cant figure it out.

```
int main(){
    while(1){
            int status;
            char work[100];
            char** arr = new char*[100];

            cout << "Enter a command:" << endl;
            cin >> arr[0];

            if(fork() != 0){
                    waitpid(-1, &status, 0);
            }else{
                    execlp(arr[0], "ls", NULL);
            }
    }
```

Comment: To save the input in the first position of the char**.

Comment: How would you enter a pointer to a `char`? Are you aware of `std::string`?

Comment: @M.M What makes you think `arr[0]` evaluates to null? The values stored in the dynamically allocated array are indeterminate; anything could be stored in there; some compiler (configurations) may give you deterministic results, but there's no guarantee...

Comment: @Helper `cin >>` with `char *` writes to memory that already exists where the `char *` is pointing, it does not allocate memory

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow and C++. It seems you want to generate/fill a variable length array of strings. In C++ we would use a `std::vector<std::string>` for that.

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
char** arr = new char*[100];
```

This is an array of POINTERS, uninitialized pointers to be precise.
They could point anywhere...

Try this instead:

```cpp
char* arr = new char[100]; // your going to leak this btw
```

Now you have a block of 100 chars, still uninitialized!

Your `cin` isn't safe, you need to be using `getline` or something similar.
Ever heard of buffer overflow?